# Eclipse project names changing

Tags: java, eclipse

When I first start Eclipse, I can see a couple of my projects in Project Explorer.  A few seconds later, the names change to "Java Main Sources" and "Java Test Sources."  Why does Eclipse do this and how can I stop it from happening?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us?

Comment: I figured it out (see self answer below) but would still like to know what these replacement names mean.  I will post a screenshot when I'm not on mobile.

Comment: added screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse is starting in the Debug perspective.  Clicking the "Open Perspective" button in the upper right and selecting Java brings the project names back.